# Are X.X.X.255/30 and X.X.X.253/30 in the same range?

Tags: networking, ip, subnet, mask

According to wiki: "The first address in a subnet is used to identify the subnet itself. The last address is used as a local broadcast address for all devices on the subnet."

How would this work in this specific case? I know that you are technically speaking allowed to allocate the IP X.X.88.0 to a device in a subnet X.X.88.0/24, but what does that mean when it comes to broadcasting for the example in the title? Would that mean that I can allocate the IP X.X.X.253 to a device, but I can't allocate X.X.X.255? Am I even "allowed" to use .255 as a subnet identifier?

What about X.X.X.254/30? Wouldn't that technically speaking cover the same range of .253, .254 and .255?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example (x.x.x.255/30) the first 30 bit of the ip-address address the network. For x.x.x.255/30 that would be x.x.x.252 with the last two bits set to zero.
The broadcast address (all host bits set to 1) of this network is then x.x.x.255
This leaves x.x.x.253 and x.x.x.254 as usable host addresses.

> Would that mean that I can allocate the IP X.X.X.253 to a device, but
>   I can't allocate X.X.X.255?

Correct.

> Am I even "allowed" to use .255 as a subnet identifier?

No.

> What about X.X.X.254/30? Wouldn't that technically speaking cover the
>   same range of .253, .254 and .255?

x.x.x.254/30 doesn't cover any range as it is one of two possible host addresses in the x.x.x.252/30 subnet.

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate the first part a bit? As far as I understand: If I had 3 isolated routers and I would set the subnet of the first one to .255/30, the subnet of the second one to 254/30 and the subnet of the third one to 253/30, the IP range in the said network would be exactly the same (broadcasting at 255), the only thing that would differ would be the identifier? But they can not co-exists on the same router?

Comment: Again, you can't set a subnet to a host address!! Are you familiar with binary numbers? With a subnet of /30 the last two bit (32 - 30 = 2) are used to address the hosts in that subnet. For subnets with a netmask of /30 the possible last quadruple of the ipv4 network address is either 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, ... 240, 244, 248, or 252.  On this subnet (x.x.x.252/30) you could define two host addresses (x.x.x.253/30 and x.x.x.254/30).

Comment: One would be the ip address used by your router and the other one the ip address of a host connected to your router. As /30 subnets allow for only 2 hosts, they are usually used for point-to-point connections. Also, for the network to be unique within your routable networks, the network address of this subnet has to be unique. Therefore, if your three routers are not within the same network, and would not use this point-to-point subnet to connect to each other, you could define the same subnet (e.g. x.x.x.252/30) to one of each routers interface.

Comment: You keep referring to x.x.x.252/30, while I was asking about x.x.x.253/30. Is that for a reason, or just a misunderstanding? I was just curious what would happen if you created 253/30, 254/30 and 255/30 subnet on the same router - 1. the router wouldn't allow it, 2. as 253/30 already covers that range, it would inform me that the subnet already exists, 3. it would create a rule conflict and none of the networks would work.

Comment: You can not define a subnet x.x.x.253/30 !!! To understand subneting, you need to understand the binary number system. In short, each quadruple of the IP address has 8 bit, which comes to a total of 32 bit (4x8bit). If you use 30 bit (/30) as a network address, then the first three quadruple and the first six bit of the last quadruple are used as a network address. All of those six bit set to one equals a decimal value of 252 and therefore the address of your network is `x.x.x.252/30`

Comment: With the remaining two bits as a possible host address you could have a decimal value of 0,1,2 or 3. Given that the 'host value' of 0 equals the network address (252 + 0 = 252) and the 'host value' of 3 (all host bits set to 1) equals the broadcast address in this subnet (252 + 3 = 255) leaves you with two host addresses (.253 and .254) in this subnet, which can't be defined as a subnet by itself. Therefore x.x.x.253/30 and x.x.x.254/30 are no valid subnet definitions. If your router will accept such a network definition or let you know that this is not possible, depends on the router.

Comment: It seems that I had wrong information, because I thought that setting a subnet to x.x.x.253/30 would set the network address to x.x.x.252 and the broadcast to x.x.x.255, leaving x.x.x.253 and x.x.x.254 free to use. I'm glad it doesn't work like that, because it made little sense to me. Last question. What would happen if you set one subnet to x.x.x.100/30 and the second one to x.x.x.103/30? The broadcast of the first one would be x.x.x.103 which should create a conflict with the second subnet, therefore making it invalid? You have been very helpful.

Comment: When you create subnets with `/30` the last quadruple will be one of 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, ..., 96, 100, 104, ..., 244, 248 or 252. Therefore x.x.x.103/30 is not a valid subnet address.

Comment: So a subnet with `/29` would only work in increments of 8 (0, 8, 16, ..) and `/28` in increments of 16 (0,  16, 32, ..)? Could you point me to some documentation, so that I may read more, because I never heard about it before. I was 100% that I can create a subnet with x.x.x.103/29 and have have /103 set as subnet identifier, /110 as brodcast and /104-107 as range. I mean, it does make sense with /24, because it's impossible to have subnet id set as anything but 0 and identifier as 255.